# Why does PHP prefer __call() to __callStatic()?

Tags: php

When I try this :

```
<?php
class myParent {
    public function __call($method, $params) {
        echo "from __call";
    }

    public function __callStatic($method, $params) {
        echo "from __callStatic";
    }
}

class mySon extends myParent {
    public function bar() {
        myParent::foo();
    }
}

(new mySon())->bar();
```

I expect this output : `from __callStatic` ...

Instead it gives : `from __call`.

Can someone explain me why ?

---

**EDIT:** To be exact I was wondering why if I delete the `__call` function, then it triggers `__callStatic` and if there's a way to trigger `__callStatic` when `__call` is declared.

Comment: (new mySon()) is an object. You called the method bar() on that object, which calls foo() for the object's parent class, which is part of the object itself. At no time, does it make a static reference to anything.

Comment: And if you remove `extends myParent` - you get what you need, as classes no longer connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things happen here, first of all: PHP supports `classname::method` as an *alias* for `parent::method`, and a way to skip certain classes in the tree [as demonstrated here](https://3v4l.org/RiiL4).

Second, `parent::` is not a static call, and it's impossible to statically call methods on parents, using either `parent::` or `classname::`. I actually opened a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62333) but this didn't trigger any developer into making this any better.

Both of these combined results in the non-intuitive behavior you're seeing

Answer (score 3):

You called the function statically **but from within an instance of the class**. So PHP called the instance based `__call()`. Note that this code is functionally equivalent to what you wrote statically

```
class mySon extends myParent {
    public function bar() {
        $this->foo(); // works the same way as myParent::foo();
    }
}
```

If you called it like so, you'd get the static (note, `__callStatic()` has to be static itself)

```
class myParent {
    public function __call($method, $params) {
        echo "from __call";
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $params) {
        echo "from __callStatic";
    }
}
myParent::foo();
```

Comment: But why when I remove the `__call` function, then `__callStatic` is called ?
Is there any way I can trigger `__callStatic` from the `bar()` function ?

Comment: @JohnSaucisse As mentioned in other comments, if you remove the `extends` then the class is no longer an instance of the one you're trying to call statically. As to why `__callStatic` gets called without `__call`, it probably has to do with order of operations

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an obvious solution for what I wanted to do :

```
class mySon extends myParent {
    public function bar() {
        myParent::__callStatic('foo', array());
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked **why**, which was explained. A workaround doesn't explain the reason and thus is not a valid answer to the question