# PHP: __call called instead of __callStatic

Tags: php

I'm developing a custom ORM and here's a simplified example to demo the issue:

```
class Foo {
    public static function __callStatic($name, $args){
        if($name == "getBar"){
            return "Bar";
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    public function __call($name, $args){
        if($name == "getFoo"){
            $model = "Foo";
            $method = "getBar";            
            return $model::$method();            
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

class Foo2 {
    public function __call($name, $args){
        if($name == "getFoo"){
            $model = "Foo";
            $method = "getBar";            
            return $model::$method();            
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

echo Foo::getBar();//Bar

$foo = new Foo;
var_dump($foo->getFoo()); //Null though I'm expecting Bar

$foo = new Foo2;
var_dump($foo->getFoo()); //Bar
```

So why same method when called inside Foo triggers `__call` and inside `Foo2` triggers `__callStatic`?

Comment: Funny thing. Obviously `__callStatic` only works from other classes and not from itself? Nice to know!

Comment: Looks more like you cannot call `__callStatic` from `__call`. Or maybe PHP fails with stacked overloading or maybe this feature is disabled for a reason.

Comment: @tilz0R It is called from __call in the 3rd approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because in the first call where you get `Null` returned, your in an object context. So it is calling `__call()` instead of `__callStatic()`.

**EDIT:** In the first case, Foo::getBar() is called in the scope of an instance of class Foo, so Foo::getBar() is actually the same as (instance)->getBar() which of course isn't a static call.

**EDIT2:** Just found a question + answer regarding your question: [Why does PHP prefer __call() to __callStatic()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139042/why-does-php-prefer-call-to-callstatic?rq=1)

Comment: In the `Foo2` example they're also in an object context, yet it behaves differently…

Comment: @deceze See the edit please. I tried to explain it a little bit more.

Comment: It would be good to see some docs regarding it. Weird PHP checks whether static methods are called inside the instance of the same class (I consider it shouldn't matter

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense.