# Why __call is being invoked instead of __callStatic

Tags: php

I tried to refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747614/php-call-called-instead-of-callstatic) on SO, but still don't get it.

```
<?php

class A {
    public function __call($method, $parameters) {
        echo "I'm the __call() magic method".PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters) {
        echo "I'm the __callStatic() magic method".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function bar() {
        A::foo();
    }

    public function foo() {
        parent::foo();
    }
}

(new B)->bar();
(new B)->foo();
```

From what I understand, the `bar` function is calling the `foo` method on class `A` statically but the `foo` method call the method using the instance of `A` which is the parent of `B`. I am expecting it should gives me:

```
I'm the __callStatic() magic method
I'm the __call() magic method
```

But, apparently, I get:

```
I'm the __call() magic method
I'm the __call() magic method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From relevant [issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62333):

> ...`A::foo()` *is not necessarily a static call*. Namely, if `foo()` is not static and there is a compatible context (`$this` exists and its class is either the class of the target method or a subclass of it), an instance call will be made.

If `foo()` is `static` it works as you expect:

```
class A {
    public function __call($method, $parameters) {
        echo "I'm the __call() magic method $method".PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters) {
        echo "I'm the __callStatic() magic method $method".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function foo() { // <-- static method
        parent::foo();
    }
}

(new B)->foo();
```

> I'm the __callStatic() magic method foo

Answer (score 3):

`A::foo()`, depending on the context, is not always a static call. Since inside `B::bar()` the `$this` object exists, *and* there isn't a static method named `foo` declared in `A`, *and* `B` is a subclass of `A`, then an instance call will be made, therefore the `__call` magic method will be invoked. When any of these conditions is not met, a static call will be made instead.